# Any Java api similar to open xml sdk 2.0?

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, openxml

Is there any **java api** which is similar to open **xml sdk 2.0**. Just I need to convert open office xml excel file to .xlsx file.

office xml excel file I'm creating by using xml and xslt. I tried **apache poi** to read xml excel file but getting invalid header format exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I believe the best API out there to handle `*.xlsx` files is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (it has `*.xlsx` support since 3.7 or so).

Some alternatives:

- There was a project called [JExcel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), but there's not much activity there in the last 3 or so years (and I'm not sure if it handles `*.xlsx` format, only `*.xls`, but I might be wrong).
- I'm not sure, but the [OpenOffice UDK](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/) might also help you. Unfortunately it is only a binding, and requires an installed implementation (i.e., you have to install [OpenOffice](http://openoffice.hu/) in order to use it), which is not always a valid requirement on the server side if you do not have any X servers there.
- Another option is something like using it through [Jacob](http://danadler.com/jacob/) via COM. The *pro* is that you are able to access all ow the data, the *con* is COM, you need an installed Excel on your machine (and of course, it is a Windows-specific solution).

**I believe the best way to stick to Apache POI**, it is usually perfectly enough if you just want to read/write cell data.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I experimented with apache poi. Here I need is to convert "Office XML Excel" to 2007 excel format .xlsx

Comment: Hm, you mean XML-based `*.xls` to `*.xlsx`? Something like [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201006.mbox/%3CH000007700853b64.1276272562.sxmail.inovex.de@MHS%3E)?

Comment: Another way to use OpenOffice/LibreOffice to do conversion is via https://github.com/mirkonasato/jodconverter

Comment: @rlegendi The format of excel is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example